How does one round off the corners?
How does one round the corners to make it look like the cube has a frame?
Like a frame made out of tubes. In this case cylinders.



Give a Skin modifier to a cube, then a Subdivision Surface modifier, CtrlA to thicken the branches in Edit mode:

Or extrude a cube 3 times:

Give it a Subdivision Surface modifier (level 1 here):

Topology if you apply the modifier and clean a bit:

